# Double curly braces {{x}} in URL crashes sharepoint

Tags: term-store, url-rewriting

It seems as if all SharePoint sites has this vulnerability. If you put anything like `{{whatever}}` in the url the site returns a 500. I.e

```
http://www.example.com/{{abc}}
```

**If you perform a lot of requests on such adresses the IIS application running the MMS crashes.**

Any ideas how to tackle this? I'm thinking of implementing some IIS UrlRewrite Regex (something like `\{\{[^}]*}}`) that removes any `{{}}` and its contents.

Thanks

Comment: Interesting. but what do you call a lot requests? like thouthads? Within a minute or a day?

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov Requests sometimes stack up a bit, this will occasionally cause 10's of requests per second which is enough to cause the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The url would crash as `{` is considered as an unsafe character, [check here](http://www.sharepointpitstop.com/2012/10/the-percent20-codes-in-url.html)
so for URL with any unsafe character you can always encode it and then use it in your code. you can encode it as `var value = SP.Utilities.HttpUtility.htmlEncode(urlString);`

Comment: Well, external systems and users can still call SharePoint using {{x}} enabling a severe exploit